# unable to compile simple java applet

Tags: java

I am trying to compile a simple java applet from the examples of [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net). I was desperate enough to try adding *everything* in the classpath.

```
$ javac -cp collections-generic-4.01.jar -cp colt-1.2.0.jar 
  -cp concurrent-1.3.4.jar -cp j3d-core-1.3.1.jar -cp jung-3d-2.0.1-sources.jar 
  -cp jung-3d-2.0.1.jar -cp jung-3d-demos-2.0.1-sources.jar -cp jung-3d-demos-2.0.1.jar 
  -cp jung-algorithms-2.0.1-sources.jar -cp jung-algorithms-2.0.1.jar 
  -cp jung-api-2.0.1-sources.jar -cp jung-api-2.0.1.jar 
  -cp jung-graph-impl-2.0.1-sources.jar -cp jung-graph-impl-2.0.1.jar 
  -cp jung-io-2.0.1-sources.jar -cp jung-io-2.0.1.jar -cp jung-jai-2.0.1-sources.jar 
  -cp jung-jai-2.0.1.jar -cp jung-jai-samples-2.0.1-sources.jar 
  -cp jung-jai-samples-2.0.1.jar -cp jung-samples-2.0.1-sources.jar 
  -cp jung-samples-2.0.1.jar -cp jung-visualization-2.0.1-sources.jar 
  -cp jung-visualization-2.0.1.jar -cp stax-api-1.0.1.jar -cp vecmath-1.3.1.jar 
  -cp wstx-asl-3.2.6.jar
```

But the result is always the same.

```
edu/uci/ics/jung/samples/AddNodeDemo.java 
edu/uci/ics/jung/samples/AddNodeDemo.java:13: package edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout does not exist
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.AbstractLayout;
                                         ^
edu/uci/ics/jung/samples/AddNodeDemo.java:14: package edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout does not exist
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.FRLayout;
                                         ^
```

And much more...

Please note that I know **nothing** about java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do multiple `-cp` switches like that. Combine them like `java -cp one:two:three` on Linux/OSX and `java -cp one;two;three` on Windows.

If you are actually interested in learning java, check out compiling with [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/).

Comment: Exactly! I tried that with CLASSPATH but probably for other reasons it did not work, so I excluded it as a possibility. thanks!

Comment: @Stefano Borini Get a notebook and write down every single thing you do. That way you can go back and analyze your steps. I've never done that, but I bought some stationary once.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing another library. To be more precise you're missing the library (.jar file) that contains the AbstractLayout and FRLayout classes in the edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout package.

Comment: `jar tf` (or your favourite zip program) to see what actually is in each jar. (`:` is the usual separator on UNIX.)

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline that would not be good advice if there is a syntax error in the compile command.